PyQt5 is it possible to have ScrollArea to scroll while dragging widget inside it?
I am trying to answer to How to Drag QLineEdit form one cell of QGridLayout to other cell in pyqt?

I have gridlayout with four cells (0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1). Every cell is vertical layout with scrollbar. Initially only (0,0) cell contains QLineEdit in it. I want to drag and drop them in any one of the cells. How can I do it?

I wrote this 3 files code :
main.py :
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget

from myui_bis import Ui_Form 


class MainWidget(QWidget, Ui_Form):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.printAcceptDrops)
        
        self.show()
        
    def printAcceptDrops(self):
        
        print('printAcceptDrops : ')

        print('Mainwidget : ', self.acceptDrops())

        print('self.scrollAreaWidgetContents : ', self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.acceptDrops())       
        print('self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2 : ', self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.acceptDrops())   
        print('self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3 : ', self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.acceptDrops())   
        print('self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4 : ', self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4.acceptDrops()) 
        
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWidget()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

my mywidgets.py :
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit, QWidget, QScrollArea, QScroller

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QMimeData
from PyQt5.QtGui import QDrag, QPixmap, QCursor

from PyQt5 import QtGui

from PyQt5 import QtCore

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class MyLineEdit(QLineEdit):
    
    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):

        print('ENTER DRAG EVENT IN ', self.objectName())
        
        e.accept()
        
        
    def dropEvent(self, e):
        
        widget = e.source()
        
        print('\n dropped on widget !!!!!!!!!!!!\n\n')
        
        
        if widget == self :
            
            return
        
        if widget.parent().layout().count() == 1:
            
            print('=============== 1   qlineedit')
            
            widget.parent().layout().parent().setAcceptDrops(True)
        
       
        widget.setParent(None)
        
self.parent().layout().insertWidget(self.parent().layout().indexOf(self) , widget)
       
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):

        if e.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
            drag = QDrag(self)
            mime = QMimeData()
            drag.setMimeData(mime)

            pixmap = QPixmap(self.size())
            self.render(pixmap)
            drag.setPixmap(pixmap)

            drag.exec_(Qt.MoveAction)
            
            
class MyWidget(QWidget):
    
    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        
        print('ENTER DRAG EVENT IN ', self.objectName())
        
        print('self.layout.count()', self.layout().count())
        
        e.accept()
        
    def dropEvent(self, e):
        
        pos = e.pos()
        
        widget = e.source()
        
        print('pos : ', pos, 'mouse : ', QCursor.pos())
        print('event.source : ', widget , 'event.source.parent() :', widget.parent())
        
        print('event.source  name: ', widget.objectName()) 
        
        print('parent : ', self.parent() , self.parent().objectName())
        
        print('self.layput() : ', self.layout())
        
        print('self.objectName() : ', self.objectName())
        
        if widget.parent().layout().count() == 1:
            
            print('=============== 1   WIDGET')
            
            widget.parent().layout().parent().setAcceptDrops(True)

        if self.layout().count() == 0 :
            
            widget.setParent(None)
            
            self.layout().addWidget(widget)
            
            self.setAcceptDrops(False)
            
        
class MyScrollArea(QScrollArea):
    
    def __init__(self , parent = None):
        super(MyScrollArea, self).__init__(parent)
           

my PyQt5-Designer ui file translated with pyuic5 myui_bis :
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QMimeData
from PyQt5.QtGui import QDrag


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(698, 672)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(Form.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        Form.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        Form.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.scrollArea_3 = MyScrollArea(Form)
        self.scrollArea_3.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollArea_3.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scrollArea_3.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea_3.setObjectName("scrollArea_3")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3 = MyWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 315, 303))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents_3")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setSpacing(30)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.scrollArea_3.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea_3, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.scrollArea_4 = MyScrollArea(Form)
        self.scrollArea_4.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollArea_4.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scrollArea_4.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea_4.setObjectName("scrollArea_4")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4 = MyWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 315, 303))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents_4")
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setSpacing(30)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName("verticalLayout_4")
        self.scrollArea_4.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea_4, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.scrollArea_2 = MyScrollArea(Form)
        self.scrollArea_2.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollArea_2.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scrollArea_2.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea_2.setObjectName("scrollArea_2")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2 = MyWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 315, 304))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents_2")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setSpacing(30)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.scrollArea_2.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.scrollArea = MyScrollArea(Form)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.scrollArea.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.scrollArea.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.scrollArea.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = MyWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, -304, 315, 897))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(30)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.lineEdit_1 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_1.setObjectName("lineEdit_1")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_1)
        self.lineEdit_2 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2)
        self.lineEdit_3 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_3)
        self.lineEdit_4 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_4)
        self.lineEdit_5 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_5.setObjectName("lineEdit_5")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_5)
        self.lineEdit_15 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_15.setObjectName("lineEdit_15")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_15)
        self.lineEdit_14 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_14.setObjectName("lineEdit_14")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_14)
        self.lineEdit_13 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_13.setObjectName("lineEdit_13")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_13)
        self.lineEdit_12 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_12.setObjectName("lineEdit_12")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_12)
        self.lineEdit_11 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_11.setObjectName("lineEdit_11")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_11)
        self.lineEdit_10 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_10.setObjectName("lineEdit_10")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_10)
        self.lineEdit_9 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_9.setObjectName("lineEdit_9")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_9)
        self.lineEdit_8 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_8.setObjectName("lineEdit_8")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_8)
        self.lineEdit_7 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_7.setObjectName("lineEdit_7")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_7)
        self.lineEdit_6 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_6.setObjectName("lineEdit_6")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_6)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.setColumnStretch(1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.setRowStretch(1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.lineEdit_1.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        self.lineEdit_2.setText(_translate("Form", "2"))
        self.lineEdit_3.setText(_translate("Form", "3"))
        self.lineEdit_4.setText(_translate("Form", "4"))
        self.lineEdit_5.setText(_translate("Form", "5"))
        self.lineEdit_15.setText(_translate("Form", "6"))
        self.lineEdit_14.setText(_translate("Form", "7"))
        self.lineEdit_13.setText(_translate("Form", "8"))
        self.lineEdit_12.setText(_translate("Form", "9"))
        self.lineEdit_11.setText(_translate("Form", "10"))
        self.lineEdit_10.setText(_translate("Form", "11"))
        self.lineEdit_9.setText(_translate("Form", "12"))
        self.lineEdit_8.setText(_translate("Form", "13"))
        self.lineEdit_7.setText(_translate("Form", "14"))
        self.lineEdit_6.setText(_translate("Form", "15"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Check AcceptDrops"))

from mywidgets import MyLineEdit, MyScrollArea, MyWidget

Now, the QLineEdit Widgets are added to the scrollAreas layouts when these are empty but then their acceptDrops attribute is set to False and the next QLineEdit widgets have to be dropped on the already present ones taking their layout-index positions within the layouts. When no widgets are left in a layout its acceptDrops value is set to True again.
The only problem now is that I cannot scroll and drag at the same time in any of the four scrollAreas, but that glitch was present in the previous answer too.

I finally realized that in PyQt5 (correct me if I am wrong) ScrollArea scroll only using the mouse wheel or by dragging the ScrollBar itself.
So I was wondering if there is a way to accomplish the result of having the dragging scrolling the area at the same time ?
I've heard about QScroller but I am not sure about what it does and tryed to to figure out what event I should filter when the drag is carried out but I wasn't able to find any clue, moreover I should be able to figure out the vertical component of the mouse drag to in some way forward the same to the ScrollArea or ScrollArea.viewport (I am not even sure I really understand what a viewport is!)

You need to override dragMoveEvent() and check whether the event is near the edges of the scroll area, then use a QTimer to eventually update the values of the scroll bar.

@musicamante first of all thank you very much indeed as always ... but any hint of sort ? I am already overriding dragMoveEvernt() to show the widget while dragging. How do I get the coords of the area ? Is the position of mouse just event.pos() would it be global or on the scrollarea or or the srollareawidgetcontent ? How do I update the scrollbar

mouse/drag events always provide mouse position in local (pos()) and global (globalPos()) coordinates. In case of QAbstractScrollArea subclasses, the local position is already in viewport coordinates, so you can check the boundaries of the self.viewport().rect() (not self.viewport().geometry()). And the scrollbar is simply updated by using scrollbar.setValue(scrollbar.value() + delta), where delta is the difference (>0 to scroll down, <0 to scroll up).

Thankd , I'll work on it in the w/e

I relized I am not ovverriding dragMoveEvent() but dragEnterEvent() ..... speed reading kills you

@musicamante if I put a QTimer in dragMoveEvent() of mine 4 scrollarea that at timeout fires towards an update_ScrollBar function , how do I stop the QTimer or better when I should stop it ? As far as I understood , could be wrong though , the dragMoveEvent() is called continously while mouse is moved draggind my QLineEdit thanks to overridden mouseMoveEvent

You must not create a QTimer in the dragMoveEvent. You should create a persistent QTimer as an instance attribute, then start it when you reach the edge (and if it's not active yet), otherwise stop it when you return near the center or on dragLeave.

okeydokey I am (not sure if in the best way) able to monitor the dragMoveEvent entering the edges of my scrollAreaContents widgets from there I can call the update_ScrollBar function but was worried about QTimer , thanks. Actually I was adding dragMoveEvent to my scrollArea after their instantiaation, I didnt now if it was bad or good ideaa but was the only way I figured out without having rewriting my promote widgets (-think I'll have to do it ) , I was missing the STOP QTimer in  on dragLeave or whendrag  return near the center, thans again

Monkey patching function is technically acceptable, but usually discouraged as it makes difficult to call the base implementation when done within another class, and it's also quite unreliable for event handlers in principle. A better and safer approach would be to use event filters, but that often results in some clumsy and more complex code especially for drag&drop. Subclassing and promoting the appropriate classes is, in reality, almost always the better choice.

Thanks , it took also a while to realize that using designer to  create my ui I have to use my scrollAreaWidgetcontents (my promoted QWidget called MyWidget) parent ----> the actual scrollArea to access the verticalScrollBar

@musicamante Hi sorry to bother again, my Proof of Concepts works right now even if with methods and QTimer monkey patched to the instances (next step will be to REwrite promoted widgets) but it occurred to me that my way of moving QLineEdits (MyLineEdit) was relying on having AcceptDrops = False for the 4 QScrollArea, to have widgets to be inserted on top of the other. Now I realized that without AcceptDrops = True I cannot use the MyLineEdit widgets dragMoveEvent that triggers the self.timer.start(). Any idea how to have this method working for children of area that is not accepting drops??

I suggest you to take your time to fix your approach and latest changes and then either update this post or create a new one.

Okey I will do it

Thanks to @Musicamante advice, here is my code:
main.py:
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget

from myui_bis import Ui_Form 



class MainWidget(QWidget, Ui_Form):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.printAcceptDrops)
        
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.printScrollBars)
        
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.setAcceptDropsTrue)
        
         # self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setAcceptDrops(False) # try uncommenting it
        
        self.show()
        


    def setAcceptDropsTrue(self):
        
        print('self.scrollAreaWidgetContents : ', self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.acceptDrops())       
        print('self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2 : ', self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.acceptDrops())   
        print('self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3 : ', self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.acceptDrops())   
        print('self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4 : ', self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4.acceptDrops()) 
        
        
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.layout().parent().setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.layout().parent().setAcceptDrops(True)     
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.layout().parent().setAcceptDrops(True)    
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4.layout().parent().setAcceptDrops(True)     
        
        
        print('self.scrollAreaWidgetContents : ', self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.acceptDrops())       
        print('self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2 : ', self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.acceptDrops())   
        print('self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3 : ', self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.acceptDrops())   
        print('self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4 : ', self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4.acceptDrops()) 
        
        

        
    def printAcceptDrops(self):
        
        print('printAcceptDrops : ')


        print('Mainwidget : ', self.acceptDrops())

        print('self.scrollAreaWidgetContents : ', self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.acceptDrops())       
        print('self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2 : ', self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.acceptDrops())   
        print('self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3 : ', self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.acceptDrops())   
        print('self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4 : ', self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4.acceptDrops()) 
        
    
    def printScrollBars(self):
        
        self.scrollArea.verticalScrollBar().setValue(self.scrollArea.verticalScrollBar().maximum())
        
       
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWidget()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

mywidgets.py:


from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit, QWidget, QScrollArea

from PyQt5.QtGui import QDrag, QPixmap, QCursor

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QMimeData, QTimer


class MyLineEdit(QLineEdit):
    
    def __init__(self , parent = None):
        super(MyLineEdit, self).__init__(parent)
    
    
    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        
        e.accept()
        
        
    def dropEvent(self, e):
        
        
        widget = e.source()
        
        print('\n dropped on widget !!!!!!!!!!!!\n\n')
        
        
        if widget == self :
            
            return
        
        
        if widget.parent().layout().count() == 1:
            
            print('=============== 1   qlineedit')
            
            widget.parent().layout().parent().setAcceptDrops(True)
        
       
        widget.setParent(None)
        
        
        self.parent().layout().insertWidget(self.parent().layout().indexOf(self) , widget)
        
        
    
    
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):

        if e.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
            
            drag = QDrag(self)
            mime = QMimeData()
            drag.setMimeData(mime)

            pixmap = QPixmap(self.size())
            self.render(pixmap)
            drag.setPixmap(pixmap)

            drag.exec_(Qt.MoveAction)
            
            

            
class MyWidget(QWidget):
    
    def __init__(self , parent = None):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.timer =  QTimer()
        
        self.timer.timeout.connect(lambda timer = self.timer : self.update_ScrollBar(timer))
        
        
    
    def dragMoveEvent(self, e):
         
        self.timer.start(1000) # time in milliseconds.
        
    def dragLeaveEvent(self , e) :
    
        print('DRAG LEAVED !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
        
        self.timer.stop()
    
        print('TIMER STOPPED')
    
    
    def update_ScrollBar(self , timer):
        
        coords = self.parent().rect().getRect()
        
        yup = coords[1]
        
        ydown = coords[1]+coords[3]
        
        ycurs =  self.parent().mapFromGlobal(QCursor().pos()).y() #### OK

        
        if abs(yup - ycurs) < 80 :
            
            print(abs(yup - ycurs) , yup , ycurs)
            
            self.parent().parent().verticalScrollBar().setValue(self.parent().parent().verticalScrollBar().value() - 80)
            
            timer.stop()
            
        elif abs(ydown - ycurs) < 80 :
            
            self.parent().parent().verticalScrollBar().setValue(self.parent().parent().verticalScrollBar().value() + 80)
            
            timer.stop()
        
        else:
        
            timer.stop()
            
            print('TIMER STOPPED')

    
    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        
        
        print('ENTER DRAG EVENT IN ', self.objectName())
        
        print('self.layout.count()', self.layout().count())
        
        e.accept()
        
        
    def dropEvent(self, e):
        
        widget = e.source()
        
        
        if widget.parent().layout().count() == 1:
            
            print('=============== 1   WIDGET')
            
            widget.parent().layout().parent().setAcceptDrops(True)
            
        
        if self.layout().count() == 0 :
            
            
            widget.setParent(None)
            
            self.layout().addWidget(widget)
            
            self.setAcceptDrops(False)
            

class MyScrollArea(QScrollArea):
    
    def __init__(self , parent = None):
        super(MyScrollArea, self).__init__(parent)
     

my PyQt5-Designer ui file translated with pyuic5 myui_bis :
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(757, 708)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(Form.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        Form.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        Form.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.scrollArea_4 = MyScrollArea(Form)
        self.scrollArea_4.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollArea_4.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scrollArea_4.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea_4.setObjectName("scrollArea_4")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4 = MyWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 344, 302))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents_4")
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(-1, 30, -1, 30)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setSpacing(30)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName("verticalLayout_4")
        self.scrollArea_4.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea_4, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.scrollArea = MyScrollArea(Form)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.scrollArea.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.scrollArea.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.scrollArea.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = MyWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 345, 945))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(-1, 30, -1, 30)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(30)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.lineEdit_1 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_1.setObjectName("lineEdit_1")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_1)
        self.lineEdit_2 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2)
        self.lineEdit_3 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_3)
        self.lineEdit_4 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_4)
        self.lineEdit_5 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_5.setObjectName("lineEdit_5")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_5)
        self.lineEdit_15 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_15.setObjectName("lineEdit_15")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_15)
        self.lineEdit_14 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_14.setObjectName("lineEdit_14")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_14)
        self.lineEdit_13 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_13.setObjectName("lineEdit_13")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_13)
        self.lineEdit_12 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_12.setObjectName("lineEdit_12")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_12)
        self.lineEdit_11 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_11.setObjectName("lineEdit_11")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_11)
        self.lineEdit_10 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_10.setObjectName("lineEdit_10")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_10)
        self.lineEdit_9 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_9.setObjectName("lineEdit_9")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_9)
        self.lineEdit_8 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_8.setObjectName("lineEdit_8")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_8)
        self.lineEdit_7 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_7.setObjectName("lineEdit_7")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_7)
        self.lineEdit_6 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_6.setObjectName("lineEdit_6")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_6)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.scrollArea_2 = MyScrollArea(Form)
        self.scrollArea_2.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollArea_2.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scrollArea_2.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea_2.setObjectName("scrollArea_2")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2 = MyWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 344, 302))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents_2")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(-1, 30, -1, 30)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setSpacing(30)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.scrollArea_2.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.scrollArea_3 = MyScrollArea(Form)
        self.scrollArea_3.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollArea_3.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scrollArea_3.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea_3.setObjectName("scrollArea_3")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3 = MyWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 345, 302))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents_3")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(-1, 30, -1, 30)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setSpacing(30)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.scrollArea_3.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea_3, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.setColumnStretch(1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.setRowStretch(1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.lineEdit_1.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        self.lineEdit_2.setText(_translate("Form", "2"))
        self.lineEdit_3.setText(_translate("Form", "3"))
        self.lineEdit_4.setText(_translate("Form", "4"))
        self.lineEdit_5.setText(_translate("Form", "5"))
        self.lineEdit_15.setText(_translate("Form", "6"))
        self.lineEdit_14.setText(_translate("Form", "7"))
        self.lineEdit_13.setText(_translate("Form", "8"))
        self.lineEdit_12.setText(_translate("Form", "9"))
        self.lineEdit_11.setText(_translate("Form", "10"))
        self.lineEdit_10.setText(_translate("Form", "11"))
        self.lineEdit_9.setText(_translate("Form", "12"))
        self.lineEdit_8.setText(_translate("Form", "13"))
        self.lineEdit_7.setText(_translate("Form", "14"))
        self.lineEdit_6.setText(_translate("Form", "15"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "ScrollBar 1 Maximum"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Check AcceptDrops"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Form", "Set AcceptDrops True"))


from mywidgets import MyLineEdit, MyScrollArea, MyWidget

Here's a widget preview :

My proof of concept works right (kind of slow updating the ScrollBar position but think it could be improved changing QTimer timeout:  self.timer.start(timeout in milliseconds)) but it occurred to me that my way of moving QLineEdits (MyLineEdit) is relying on having AcceptDrops = False for the 3 QScrollArea, to have widgets to be inserted on top of the other. In fact only setting AcceptDrops = False I can show the user a Forbidden symbol while releasing/hoovering the Left Mouse button to drop the widget in the Scrollarea instead of on top of another widget, otherwise the user won't notice that thinking about having moved the widget while it remains in its old ScrollArea.
In the first (top left) ScrollArea that property is set to True so that I can move the ScrollBar while Dragging hovering the widgets. Now I realized that without AcceptDrops = True I cannot use the MyLineEdit widgets dragMoveEvent that triggers the self.timer.start().

I have edited this to remove a question from the answer. Answers here must be 100% answers, and contain no conversation-openers or connected questions. I think it is OK to have a statement about something that would have been nice to have gotten working, but essentially if a solution prompts a connected question, please ask the new question as a separate question.
